# Is there a way I can use a REGEX in Power Query (from Excel) without using R?

Tags: regex, excel, powerquery

I want to be able to validate email addresses (for example, will be phone numbers and VAT numbers once i can get this working)

I'm not techy enough to use R (unless it is really easy?)

I tried

`42 -match '[0-9][0-9]'`

and it errored with Token Eof expected (and a little red squigly between the  ][

UPDATE
this is a sample regex for a simple email check

`^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$`

so i would like to use this in PowerQuery

`dave@smith.com` - would be ok

`@davesmith` - fail

`davesmith.com` - fail

please let me know if i need to add more

Comment: Please update your Question with some examples of the data you are trying to match.

Comment: perhaps ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$

Comment: AFAIK, there is no Regex Support in `M`

Answer (score 2):

M doesn't have RegEx but it's possible to write validation functions with more verbose code.

For example, here's one way to write a validator function similar to your RegEx:

```
let
    IsValidEmail = (input as text) =>
    let
        name = Text.BeforeDelimiter(input,"@",{0,RelativePosition.FromEnd}),
        ext = Text.AfterDelimiter(input,".",{0,RelativePosition.FromEnd}),
        domain = Text.BetweenDelimiters(input,name&"@","."&ext),
        return =
            Text.Length(name) > 0 and
            Text.Length(domain) > 0 and
            Text.Length(ext) > 1 and Text.Length(ext) < 6 and
            name = Text.Select(name, {"a".."z","A".."Z","0".."9","_","-","."}) and
            domain = Text.Select(domain, {"a".."z","A".."Z","0".."9","_","-","."}) and
            ext = Text.Select(ext, {"a".."z","A".."Z"})
    in
        return
in
    IsValidEmail
```